# ToolStripProgressBar is not accessible

Tags: c#, winforms

I added `StatusStrip` to my form and then 2 items to this strip: `ToolStripStatusLabel` and `ToolStripProgressBar`.

VS (2010) created following code in the designer file:

```
this.statusLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
...
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar progressBar;
```

So, it works for `StatusLabel` in the cs file

```
this.statusLabel.Text = "Hello world";
```

but `progressBar` variable is not accessible. Why? And how can I set `progressBar` value in this case?

Comment: Are you trying to access the progress bar in the same partial class?

Comment: Also. There is no progressBar variable declaration at the bottom of the designer file ... label variable only: private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel statusLabel;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your `ToolStripProgressBar` in the Designer view and check its `GenerateMember` property. I guess it has been set to `False` by accident.